# TensorFlow: Why does a GPU device only have one device context (and does it *really*)?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to make some decisions about how to handle the resources I have available to communicate with the system I'm porting for TensorFlow.  I'm trying to understand the code in BaseGPUDevice::Init() [after line 209.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L209).

The code runs in a loop for `max_streams` cycles, and each time through it creates a set of streams for cross-device communication, then instantiates one `GPUDeviceContext` that will use that set of streams.

Then, in the body of `FillContextMap()`, a sophisticated function is called to determine the optimal allocation of streams among available streams.  The best stream is modulo'd against the total number of created streams in the returned map, and the map is then used to apportion 
nodes to device contexts in the rest of the function.

OK, so far, so good.  We have a system that looks like it uses a lot of code to ensure it distributes resources well.  But what throws me is that the [code to instantiate a device](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device_factory.cc#L34), which ends up hard-coding the value of `max_streams` to 1, meaning that all the context mapping code after line 279 should never get called.

Am I looking at old code that is no longer applicable, or placeholder code against a future date when GPU devices will have multiple contexts, or are there situations I haven't found in which a GPU device can be created with multiple contexts?

Comment: Just to keep this question up-to-date as I was interested in the same thing. In TensorFlow 2.1RC this dead code is removed by [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/223c8bdf8963fef00cd9a1ec0fa10a3fb47fda1e) commit with the detailed explanation of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are looking at code that is a bit stale; we've tried experimenting with multiple compute streams and have found that, so far, it hasn't helped that much in important use cases.  We technically support multiple streams, but we never turn it on.

At some point in the future, we want to start playing around with using multiple compute streams again though, so it's nice to have the code there.

Devices can use as many DeviceContexts as they want; on GPU we only use a few and we use FillContextMap to do the mapping, but it really depends on the hardware how they should be used.